# How to change a button image after selecting a row from table view - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, button, tableview

I am new to Xcode and iOS development and trying to build an app which plays few *mp3* files. The corresponding file is played when a row in a `tableview` is selected. I have created a play button (custom button) with `PlayButton` Icon. What I am trying to do here is:

1. When I select a row, the song plays and then the image should change from Play to Pause
2. So far I have been able to program the Play button such that if the song is playing the button image toggles to Pause/Play.

What I need help with is:

1. How do I access the custom button from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
2. How to change the image to a different image.

Any help will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `UIImageView` built into the standard `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: the buttons that I have created are outside table view. It's kind of a toolbar that I have created for my app which has play/next/previous buttons. (similar to any music app).

Comment: this information wasn't unimportant, because it sounded like the button is in the cell ^^ so my answer is useless here :P

Comment: @user2539989, why not just use an `IBOutlet` property to the button then and reference it like `self.myButton'?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your Part

1 ) Assign a tag to your custom button, lets say '10'

Now on your didSelectRowAtIndexPath try something like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *playBtn = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:10];   //This way you can acess your custom button
```

2) Its simple to assign/change image, here is how

```
    [playbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name of your image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to create a custom cell so that every cell can manage it's items by himself. A simple class that inherits from `UITableViewCell` and holds the entity for the song, the `UIButton` and some methods. Maybe also a `BOOL` value for **play/pause state**.

```
// CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
    id songEntity;
    BOOL isPlaying;
}

-(void)playSong;
-(void)pauseSong;

@end


// CustomCell.m
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) 
    {
        isPlaying = NO;
        // init button...
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"];
        [playButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)playSong
{
    // ...
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton.png"];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)pauseSong
{
    // ...
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

//...
@end
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I will try both the solutions. Appreciate your help. So far this has been the toughest part of logic for me in building the app. :)

Comment: This is what I tried and it worked:

    UIButton *playBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:10];   
    [playBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PauseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

The standard (and simple) to reference any static (not on a cell) view such as a UIButton is to enable the Assistant Editor in XCode and CTRL-drag the item to the interface section of the .h file from Interface Builder.

This creates an `IBOutlet` property for the item. XCode will prompt you to name the property.

If you name the `IBOutlet` "playButton", then you reference it like `self.playButton` from the same view controller.